# service httpd restart failure on aws amazon linux ami

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, amazon-web-services

Thanks for your help. I recently did the following:

1. Ran `sudo yum update` on my ec2 instance running the Amazon Linux ami
2. I then added a virtual host to my vhost.conf for a subdomain.
3. While the server is still accessible, When I ran `sudo httpd restart` I received the following:

.

```
Stopping httpd:                                            [FAILED]
Starting httpd: AH00548: NameVirtualHost has no effect and will be removed in the next release /etc/httpd/conf.d/vhost.conf:1
(98)Address already in use: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:80
(98)Address already in use: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80
no listening sockets available, shutting down
AH00015: Unable to open logs
                                                           [FAILED]
```

Also, if I run the restart command without sudo `service httpd restart` I receive the following message:

```
rm: cannot remove `/var/run/httpd/httpd.pid': Permission deniedLED]

rm: cannot remove `/var/run/httpd/httpd.pid': Permission denied
Starting httpd: AH00548: NameVirtualHost has no effect and will be removed in the next release /etc/httpd/conf.d/vhost.conf:1
(13)Permission denied: AH00058: Error retrieving pid file /var/run/httpd/httpd.pid
AH00059: Remove it before continuing if it is corrupted.
                                                           [FAILED]
```

Comment: Looks like something's already running on port 80.

Comment: @ceejayoz, thanks for the response. I'm new to linux. How can I figure that out and then work a solution? Thanks!

Comment: @MSchwartz Seems like you are in over your head. I would recommend just rebooting the whole server in lieu of anything else.

Comment: I fixed this by going into `sudo -i` then stopping and starting the service explicitly.

Answer (score 3):

From what you have provided seems that there is another process using port 80

Try to  do the following:

First you need to be a root user to execute them, either you add sudo before the command, or before doing anything, switch to the user root like this:

```
su -root
```

and type the root password.

Then, proceed with:

```
netstat -tulpn| grep :80
```

The above command displays list of connections that are using port 80

Then execute the following command to kill the process that is using port 80

```
kill -9 <process id>
```

Replace process id with the process number that is shown on the screen from the previous command.

Then execute this command to start httpd process:

```
service httpd start
```

If the above did not work with you then try this

Try this i have just tested it:

```
for i in `lsof -i :80 | grep http | awk {' print $2'}`; do kill -9 $i; done
```

Then perform the restart:

```
service httpd restart
```

Comment: Thanks @MohyedeenN. After I ran `netstat` I got `tcp        0      0 :::80                       :::*                        LISTEN      12660/httpd`. I then killed process 12660 and ran the `netstat` command again which then showed `tcp        0      0 :::80                       :::*                        LISTEN      13831/httpd`. Is there a reason it's auto starting? After `service httpd start` I received this on the following comment:

Comment: `Starting httpd: AH00548: NameVirtualHost has no effect and will be removed in the next release /etc/httpd/conf.d/vhost.conf:1
(98)Address already in use: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:80
(98)Address already in use: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80
no listening sockets available, shutting down
AH00015: Unable to open logs
                                                           [FAILED]`

Comment: @MSchwartz Please see at the end of my answer i have added a piece of code execute it then restart httpd.

Comment: no luck, same message  :/   Anything with the "AH00015: Unable to open logs" error? Also, running `service httpd restart` without root gives me this:

`rm: cannot remove '/var/run/httpd/httpd.pid': Permission deniedLED]

rm: cannot remove '/var/run/httpd/httpd.pid': Permission denied
Starting httpd: AH00548: NameVirtualHost has no effect and will be removed in the next release /etc/httpd/conf.d/vhost.conf:1
(13)Permission denied: AH00058: Error retrieving pid file /var/run/httpd/httpd.pid
AH00059: Remove it before continuing if it is corrupted. [FAILED]`

Comment: If this is not working for you, then why not just reboot the whole server? That should clear it up.

Comment: @MSchwartz do you still have the 'could not bind to address' (meaning there's still a process there that you need to stop, or configure Apache to run in another port) or it's just the log message? for the log, make sure the filepath indicated in the apache config file exists, you may need to create the log file (with 'touch' for example) and make sure apache user can write to it

Comment: @MohyedeenN sending SIGKILL as a first attempt at killing a process is a bad idea since it can't clean up.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the user:

```
id
```

Check out the permission:

```
ls -l /var/run/httpd/httpd.pid
```

Run it to get `<process id>`:

```
netstat -tulpn| grep :80
```

To check out who ran the httpd:

```
ps -ef|grep <process id>
```

Answer (score 0):

So the answer about another process using port 80 or 443 or something is probably correct more or less, but this looks like a classic mistake which I thought I'd share. You should never ever kill -9 `pidof httpd` or otherwise kill apache abruptly. If you do, you will get that error until the system kills all the remaining tcp connections to/from port 80. Try netstat -alpn | grep ':80' and check if there's a bunch of connections in TCP_TIME_WAIT or something like that. You have to leave the apache server off until these ALL disappear.

Obviously you could also have a problem like having nginx or lighttpd runnning on the same machine, blocking the ports, but I bet someone killed apache. It'll take like two minutes for all those connections to go away.